# R studio blank white screen

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running an MCMC analysis that requires 20 million simulations and I left MCMC to run for a few days only to come back to an RStudio page that was completely blank and nothing is operational. Are there any fixes so that I don’t have to restart and lose what I was attempting with my mcmc? Or a way I can save my data without viewing it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is the "RStudio White Screen of Death". It seems to be irreversible at that stage. I tried waiting forever for it, saving the session, to no avail. The solution seems to be buying more RAM.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-white-screen-of-death/132309

I prepared for it by saving certain processed data as .RData file before export out in excel (required by my work) or doing other steps that take a lot of memory/run for a long time.